# Detect windows touch laptop with modernizer

Tags: javascript, touch, modernizr

I have sample code where script detect touch device and perform an operation.

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
   return;
}
```

While using Windows 8 with touch enabled laptop it go into this condition and some functions of the scripts not work on desktop devices because it can detect touch event in laptop.

Is there any java-script detection condition which can detect Windows 8-10 with touch device and perform some action?

Comment: why do you want to detect a touch screen? what browsers are you wanting to have this detect in